# Is R2DBC only for Java applications?

Tags: java, r2dbc

Is the R2DBC specification only for Java applications? Because I only find Java examples on the Internet.

And what about the thread-per-request problem? Doesn't this exist in other programming languages?

Comment: R2DBC is a specification for Java reactive database connections - yes. Strictly JVM rather than just Java. It’s analogous to JDBC. Other languages have other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is R2DBC-specification only for Java applications?

[R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) is implemented in Java, which means it can be used in Java as well as other JVM languages, such as kotlin, scala, etc.

> and what about thread-per-request problem? Doesn't this exist in other programming languages?

Assuming you are talking about the benefits of going non-blocking also with database interactions, the problem is independent of the language / platform you're working on, so yes, this also exists elsewhere.

But just like JDBC is a Java-only API for blocking database interaction, R2DBC is a Java-only API for non-blocking (reactive, specifically) database interaction.

Both can be used in Java, kotlin, scala, etc., i.e. on the JVM only.